# How to add post meta in while loop?

Tags: php, loop, post-meta, forms, html

I've got the post id from the meta value and used while loop to show them. Now my problem is that I also need a form to add another meta value (e.g. 1,2,3) for meta key 'rank' to each post id.

```
$args = array(
              'meta_key' => 'e_id',
              'meta_value' => $eid,
              'post_type' => 'rsvp',
              'post_status' => 'any',
              'posts_per_page' => -1
          );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<form action="" method="post"><?
      if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <input type='text' name='rank' ><?   
      endwhile;
      endif;?>
      <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Update"/>
    </form>
```

Since the form will stay on the same page after submit button is clicked so I did something like this as well, but it did not work as expected.

```
if(isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
              add_post_meta($post->ID, 'rank', $_REQUEST['rank'], true);
    }
```

I really have no idea where to put this and how to make it work with the loop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No Sir, I use it in my custom php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `init` action hook. From the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init): *init is useful for intercepting $_GET or $_POST triggers.*

*The following code is just a sample and is untested:*

```
function wpse283607_handle_submit()
{
    // check if form is POSTed and nonce is valid
    if ( 'POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
         && wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'], 'my-action' ) ) {
        if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['rank'] ) ) {
            $ranks = (array) $_REQUEST['rank'];
            foreach ( $ranks as $post_id => $rank ) {
                add_post_meta( intval( $post_id ), 'rank', intval( $rank ) );
            }
        }

        // redirect to the same page (to avoid re-submit form data on browser reload/refresh)
        wp_safe_redirect(
            remove_query_arg( [ '_wp_http_referer', '_wpnonce' ], wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) )
        );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse283607_handle_submit' );
```

Then your `<form>` would look something like:

```
<form action="" method="post"><?
    wp_nonce_field( 'my-action' );
    /**
     * @var \WP_Query $the_query
     */
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $i = 1; // not sure how you generate your "rank" but just an example
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <input type='text' name='rank[<?php echo $post->ID ?>]' value="<?php echo $i ?>" /><?
        $i++;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Update" />
</form>
```